# Are There Scientific Papers on Methods for Robustifying LLMs and Current Challenges They Face?

Tags: machine-learning, papers, research, large-language-models

I'm currently researching Large Language Models (LLMs) and am particularly interested in the recent advancements and challenges in this field. My focus is on understanding the methods being developed to make LLMs more robust and the key issues that these models are currently facing.

Could anyone point me towards scientific papers or articles that discuss methods for robustifying LLMs? I'm looking for resources that delve into techniques for improving the reliability, accuracy, and overall performance of these models under various conditions.

Comment: what does robust mean?

Comment: Avoiding syntax and similar errors and failures in producing texts with specific rules. @user253751